# After picking date and time from Date & Time Picker, how to pass them as parameters in 'Create Event' function of Calendars?

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I have a Date & Time Picker widget of Android Studio, from which i have selected a particular date(dd-mm-yy) format and time(hr:min) format.

Now, in the same `Activity` i have a 'Submit' button;by clicking on it, i pass several parameters to the 'Create Event' of my phone's native Calendar.

While i can successfully pass the title,description, location etc. i don't know how to pass the 'Start-End Date' & 'Start-End' Time parameters that i have chosen from the Date & Time Picker to the Native Calendar.

Thanks.

Here, is a brief code of the same:

1> Selecting date function:

```
private void selectDate()
{
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dpd.show();
}
```

2> Selecting Time function:

```
private void selectTime()
{
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), hourOfDay + ":" + minute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, mHour, mMinute, false);
    tpd.show();
}
```

3) On Submit button click:

```
Sb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent schedule = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        schedule.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        schedule.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,   startTime);
        schedule.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime);
        schedule.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, false);
        schedule.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Title");
        schedule.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Location");
        startActivity(schedule);
        }
    });
```

**I have edited my code to accommodate a suggestion:**

```
private void selectTime()
{
    TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
                {
                     c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                     c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), hourOfDay + ":" + minute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, mHour, mMinute, false);
    tpd.show();
}

 private void selectDate()
{
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                {
                    c.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dpd.show();
}
```

**Now, the time & date both perfectly changes/updates every time i create a new event!Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a `Calendar` instance variable:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Set its values from `onDateSet()` and `onTimeSet()`:

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
}

// ...

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
{
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
}
```

And then pass the value of this `Calendar` instance as millis from epoch:

```
schedule.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
    calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a Date object in your activity

```
private Date date = null;
```

in the constructor:

```
date = new Date();
```

in `onDateSet` set

```
date.setYear(year);
date.setMonth(monthOfYear);
date.setDate(dayOfMonth);
```

in `onTimeSet`

```
date.setHours(hourOfDay);
date.setMinutes(minute);
```

and then you can use this date in Submit function

Comment: Ok, and how do i pass this date object as 'start-end' date and 'start-end' time to the Calendar? Plz provide its syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks a little old but you can try this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCalendar/article.html
It passes a GregorianCalendar parameter to the api.

else go to the docs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html
in the **Using an intent to insert an event** section for an example.

```
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 7, 30);
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 8, 45);
endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
...

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
```